mocking a function in a process started with multiprocessing.Process
Is it possible to mock out a function in a process started with multiprocessing.Process? AI tells me it is, but I have not gotten it to work.
The use case is that I have a server I want to write tests for. I want the tests to start up the server, but I need to mock out the JWT based auth functions in the server.
If it is possible perhaps I am doing something wrong.
The function I want to mock our is in foo.bar.baz.validate_jwt`.

The server imports it as from .baz import validate_jwt. I have tried to mock it many ways, here is the latest attempt:
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def mock_get_public_key():
return PUBLIC_KEY
@patch('foo.bar.baz.validate_jwt')
def test_fn(mock_validate_jwt, mock_get_public_key):

I also tried `@patch('foo.bar.main.validate_jwt')`
But no matter I've tried the real functions get called.
Here is an example:
In directory foo/bar file baz.py
def get_public_key(token: str) -> str:
    print("in get_public_key)
def validate_jwt(token: str) -> dict
    public_key = get_public_key(token)
    print("in validate_jwt)
In directory foo/bar file main.py:
from .baz import validate_jwt
def server(token):
    valid = validate_jwt(token)
In my test code, which is in test/test_main.py (test and foo are at the same level)
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def mock_get_public_key():
    return PUBLIC_KEY

def run_server(port):
    from foo.bar.main import start
    start(is_prod=False, port=port)

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def mock_validate_jwt(token):
    return {"user": "test_user"}

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def start_server():
    port = 8002
    server_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_server, args=(port,))
    server_process.start()

    max_retries = 10
    for i in range(max_retries):
        try:
            response = requests.get(f"http://127.0.0.1:{port}/echo?message=test")
            if response.status_code == 200:
                break
        except requests.ConnectionError:
            time.sleep(1)
    else:
        pytest.fail("Server did not start in time")

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("start_server")
@patch('dispatcher.main.validate_jwt')
def test_function(mock_validate_jwt, mock_get_public_key):
    ,
    .
    .

When test_function runs the real validate_jwt runs, not my mock.
